# Unfortunately, app has stopped android when I upgrades from api 10 to api 11 or above

Tags: java, android, web-services, api

I have a android project using web services to get data from server. Initial, my project get data very ok. but something's wrong when I upgrade my project to api 11 or above, it show the error "Unfortunately myapp has stopped". Anybody give me some idea to fix it.

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.GUI.MainActivity"

            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The function to get data from server through web services:

```
public class getUserInfoBUS {


String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/myproject/api/question/";


public UserTemp getUserInfo(String Username){
    UserTemp user = new UserTemp();
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);  
    try {  
        //Parse xml
        HttpEntity r_entity = httpclient.execute(request).getEntity();
        String xmlString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity, HTTP.UTF_8);
        Log.d("result:::", xmlString) ;
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
        inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));
        Document doc = db.parse(inStream);  
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("userTemp");
        for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            if (nl.item(i).hasChildNodes()) {

                config.User_ID=nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent();
                config.User_type_ID=nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent();
                user.Password = nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(2).getTextContent();

            }
            Log.d("soluongnode:", i+"");

        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
        Log.d("exception:", e.toString()) ;
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        Log.d("exception:", e.toString());
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("exception:", e.toString());
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("exception:", e.toString());
    }  
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();   
   return user;
}
```

And my logcat

```
04-23 19:08:20.711: E/Trace(777): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-23 19:08:23.190: I/Choreographer(777): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 19:08:23.360: D/gralloc_goldfish(777): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-23 19:08:24.800: D/AndroidRuntime(777): Shutting down VM
04-23 19:08:24.800: W/dalvikvm(777): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at BusinessLogic.getUserListBUS.getUserList(getUserListBUS.java:46)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at com.example.GUI.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:75)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-23 19:08:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 19:08:25.121: D/dalvikvm(777): GC_CONCURRENT freed 248K, 14% free 2537K/2924K, paused 9ms+59ms, total 267ms
04-23 19:08:30.850: I/Process(777): Sending signal. PID: 777 SIG: 9
04-23 19:13:21.790: E/Trace(843): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-23 19:13:22.721: I/Choreographer(843): Skipped 249 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 19:13:22.741: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_CONCURRENT freed 145K, 10% free 2648K/2932K, paused 13ms+16ms, total 132ms
04-23 19:13:22.930: I/Choreographer(843): Skipped 175 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 19:13:23.040: D/gralloc_goldfish(843): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-23 19:13:23.280: I/Choreographer(843): Skipped 219 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 19:13:52.530: D/AndroidRuntime(843): Shutting down VM
04-23 19:13:52.530: W/dalvikvm(843): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at BusinessLogic.getUserListBUS.getUserList(getUserListBUS.java:46)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at com.example.GUI.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:78)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-23 19:13:52.580: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 19:14:01.671: E/Trace(866): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-23 19:14:02.570: D/dalvikvm(866): GC_CONCURRENT freed 146K, 10% free 2650K/2936K, paused 16ms+22ms, total 112ms
04-23 19:14:02.590: I/Choreographer(866): Skipped 259 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 19:14:02.751: I/Choreographer(866): Skipped 143 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 19:14:02.781: D/gralloc_goldfish(866): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-23 19:14:02.970: I/Choreographer(866): Skipped 161 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 19:14:03.460: I/Choreographer(866): Skipped 80 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 19:14:03.570: I/Choreographer(866): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 19:14:04.260: D/AndroidRuntime(866): Shutting down VM
04-23 19:14:04.260: W/dalvikvm(866): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at BusinessLogic.getUserListBUS.getUserList(getUserListBUS.java:46)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.example.GUI.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:78)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-23 19:14:04.310: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 19:14:18.130: D/dalvikvm(905): GC_CONCURRENT freed 149K, 10% free 2650K/2940K, paused 13ms+17ms, total 116ms
04-23 19:14:18.160: I/Choreographer(905): Skipped 268 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 19:14:18.341: I/Choreographer(905): Skipped 165 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 19:14:18.361: D/gralloc_goldfish(905): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-23 19:14:18.590: I/Choreographer(905): Skipped 212 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 19:14:40.210: D/AndroidRuntime(905): Shutting down VM
04-23 19:14:40.210: W/dalvikvm(905): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at BusinessLogic.getUserListBUS.getUserList(getUserListBUS.java:46)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at com.example.GUI.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:78)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-23 19:14:40.260: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 19:14:42.861: I/Process(905): Sending signal. PID: 905 SIG: 9
04-23 19:22:09.261: E/Trace(962): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-23 19:22:10.110: D/dalvikvm(962): GC_CONCURRENT freed 149K, 10% free 2646K/2936K, paused 20ms+14ms, total 117ms
04-23 19:22:10.150: I/Choreographer(962): Skipped 267 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 19:22:10.320: I/Choreographer(962): Skipped 157 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 19:22:10.340: D/gralloc_goldfish(962): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-23 19:22:10.550: I/Choreographer(962): Skipped 193 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-23 19:22:11.470: D/AndroidRuntime(962): Shutting down VM
04-23 19:22:11.470: W/dalvikvm(962): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at BusinessLogic.getUserListBUS.getUserList(getUserListBUS.java:46)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at com.example.GUI.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:78)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-23 19:22:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(962):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 19:27:11.711: I/Process(962): Sending signal. PID: 962 SIG: 9
```

Please anybody give me some ideas to fix it, thanks!

Comment: "NetworkOnMainThreadException" probably you're running your network operation on the UI thread. Do it for example in an AsyncTask or anyway not on the main thread.

Comment: here, give me some advice plz

Comment: @fasteque how to fix it?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: Put your data fetching code inside AsyncTask

Comment: In API level 11, the default is to crash if you try to access the network on the main thread. In previous API levels, it's a bad idea, but it doesn't crash. The reason it's bad is that it freezes your entire app while the network operation happens. And if the network is slow, your app freezes for a significant time. Do your users a favour and fix the problem that Android is now making obvious (by performing network access on a different thread).

Comment: please at the very least read your error

Comment: It's working, thanks everybody so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in to `OnCreate()` Method of your `MainActivity.java` class

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

**Edit Answer-**

For Api Level>=11 you have to use `AsyncTask`

```
public class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        String URL="http://10.0.2.2:8080/myproject/api/question/";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //Put your http request code here.

            UserTemp user = new UserTemp();
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);  
            try {  
                //Parse xml
                HttpEntity r_entity = httpclient.execute(request).getEntity();
                String xmlString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity, HTTP.UTF_8);
                Log.d("result:::", xmlString) ;
                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
                inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));
                Document doc = db.parse(inStream);  
                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("userTemp");
                for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    if (nl.item(i).hasChildNodes()) {

                        config.User_ID=nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent();
                        config.User_type_ID=nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent();
                        user.Password = nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(2).getTextContent();

                    }
                    Log.d("soluongnode:", i+"");

                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
                Log.d("exception:", e.toString()) ;
            } catch (IOException e) {  
                Log.d("exception:", e.toString());
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("exception:", e.toString());
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("exception:", e.toString());
            }  
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();   

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

And when you want to get data from server put following code line

```
new GetData().execute();
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Your code is recommendable to use during testing phase not in final code, because it forcefully runs it in Main thread.

Comment: As said for another answer, this is a not a very good idea. The correct design is to avoid network IO on main thread and not changing the policy to avoid system's check.

Comment: Now check my Edit Answer Please

Comment: Thanks your code, it's running but somebody said it not good for my code, can i use it?

Comment: Please use an AsyncTask, don't change the policies ;)

Comment: @user3422449 Please check my Edited answer. It will work fine. If not please let me know i will try to help you more.

Comment: @shweta_jain I did it following you said, but it still error, i put code new getUserListBUS().execute();
    tv_user.setText(config.lstUser.get(0).FullName); it error at tv_user.setText

Comment: can you please send me logcat error. what error you are getting?

Comment: where are you putting "tv_user.setText(config.lstUser.get(0).FullName)"? In which mehtod onPreExecute(), doInBackground(), onPostExecute()

Comment: Please try to put that code "tv_user.setText(config.lstUser.get(0).FullName)" in onPostExecute() Method.

Comment: I have a another stupid error and now i have fix it, thanks your enthusiasm :d

Answer (score 0):

add the following  in your code.

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = newStrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();      
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: It's more a hack or a workaround this solution because the correct design is to never run networking operation on the main thread and not bypassing the check performed by the system :)

Comment: don't. do. that. ever.

Comment: It's working, thanks everybody so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

`android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. Run your code in `AsyncTask`:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
            {

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                }
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                   UserTemp user = new UserTemp();
                  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                  HttpGet request = new HttpGet(params[0]);  
                  try {  
                   //Parse xml
                    HttpEntity r_entity = httpclient.execute(request).getEntity();
                    String xmlString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity, HTTP.UTF_8);
                    Log.d("result:::", xmlString) ;
                    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
                    inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));
                    Document doc = db.parse(inStream);  
                    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("userTemp");
                    for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    if (nl.item(i).hasChildNodes()) {

                   config.User_ID=nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent();
               config.User_type_ID=nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent();
               user.Password = nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(2).getTextContent();

            }
            Log.d("soluongnode:", i+"");

       }
         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
          Log.d("exception:", e.toString()) ;
          } catch (IOException e) {  
         Log.d("exception:", e.toString());
         } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          Log.d("exception:", e.toString());
          } catch (SAXException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          Log.d("exception:", e.toString());
          }  
         httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); 

                    return null ;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);             
                    //Update your UI here
            }
```

Execute the `AsyncTask` where ever required   like following,

```
 String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/myproject/api/question/";    
 new MyAsyncTask ().execute(URL);
```

Comment: I'm try this, but it not working, it still show Unfortunately, app has stopped, i don't know reason why? Tks your advice!

Comment: @user3422449:What error you are getting and on which line? I didn't tested the above code so you have to provide more info so that I can help.

Comment: @user3422449: If it is working then you should consider accepting this answer so that it will be helpful to other.

Comment: ok tks your remind, I'm a newbie :d

Answer (score 0):

Till Donut it is used to create multiple threads from 1.6-2.3 that you was using before but if now you are using 3.0 or above then it is used to create single threaded model by using AsyncTask otherwise you ll get the NetworkOnMainThreadException.